# Unable to get basic information by API from paypal through Grant access

Tags: php, paypal

I follow the way like https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsUsing/

I am able to get grant access as token, signature & timestamp.
But here is no specified API to get basic information.

Comment: Please be more explicit in your question: what have you tried, what were the results ? Show us some code ;)

Comment: I used this direct form url and got credential invalid error.
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/Permissions/GetBasicPersonalData?token=xxxxx&signature=xxxx=&timeStamp=xxxx&AppId=APP-xxxx

Answer (score 0):

To generate the authentication header `X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION` you need to use the [Permissions SDKs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sdks/) provided in the link you linked.

At the end of the Permissions Integration guide it advises on how to use the authorization after it's been generated.